# How can I find location of evicted cache line in L2 cache?

Tags: c++, c, caching, cpu-cache

I have an L2 cache filled with data. Now I need to write a program which will evict from L2 cache(not too sure exactly how to do this, but will figure it out) . My main doubt is if there is any method by which I can find the location of evicted lines in L2. Also is there any source from where I can find out the details of victim cache present in my system??  I feel they might play a role here during cache eviction (please correct me if I am wrong). I am using i3 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Im not aware of answer to your entire question. But there is no way to know which cache line your data is mapped to. Because you dont the set number to which your data/address is mapped in L2 cache.!

But I think you can know this if you are using HUGE PAGES which lets you know the mapping to L2 clearly.